# Logging into website with asihttprequest

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I an trying to log on to a simple web page i made, u have the code in a - (IBACTION) { }

When i press the button it is supposed to get the data

here is my code

```
-(IBAction)fetchData:(id)sender {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rssit.site90.com/login.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addPostValue:@"" forKey:@"username"];
[request addPostValue:@"" forKey:@"password"];


[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
NSLog(@"%d, %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);

}
```

When i run it, It returns 0, (null) i looked at the header file for asihttprequest and that means no authentication needed? But there is a login on that website.

Im putting in a username and password i just didnt list it on here

Comment: You might want to lookup the meaning of 'asynchronous' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite code as follows and bingo....

```
-(IBAction)fetchData:(id)sender 
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rssit.site90.com/login.php"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addPostValue:@"" forKey:@"username"];
    [request addPostValue:@"" forKey:@"password"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    //Add finish or failed selector
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestLoginFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestLoginFailed:)];

    NSLog(@"%d, %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);

}

- (void)requestLoginFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
//Check response of request here and act accordingly
NSString *yourResponse = [request responseString]; //corrected here please change it to responseString
//Parse above response and check it.
}


- (void)requestLoginFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
//some error was there processing request 
//Check error 
NSError *error = [request error];
NSLog(@"Failed ---> %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

While you make request you need to wait till request finish though you are making asynchronous request because it is login information and you need to wait till response comes.

Comment: When i try that i get  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ASIFormDataRequest response]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Sorry abt that it should be [request responseString]. I have updated my answer. Please check it again.

Comment: Okay well when i do that all it does is display the html code for the login page but it does not login

Comment: What does it print in NSLog ? Did you received proper response ?

Comment: for the http code i receive 200 and then i just receive the login pages html code, is that normal? how do i make it advance to the next page since i have the login credentials?

Comment: 200 means execution done. Now whatever your server return will be in responseString. So you need to parse it like if successful login is there it will return success. on bad username password it will return failure. You need to process accordingly. Parse received response and decide further action. On successful login redirect user to next view controller by pushing new view controller. On failure alert user about wrong credentials.